# HHVM 2.4 doesn't support HTTP DELETE method?

Tags: php, rest, hhvm, http-delete

I created a REST service using PHP which takes a DELETE HTTP method. It works perfect with apache server, but after switching to hhvm 2.4, I start to receive a 400 bad request error saying "method not implemented".

I tried to trigger the method through curl on command line, chrome and firefox. They all had the same problem. However, sending the same method through safari worked well...

I'm very confused about this result. Please let me know if you have run into any similar issues or there was something in the hhvm config that I was missing.

Comment: Please try HHVM 3.2, 2.4 is super old.